# how to replace the whole line which has a specfic word using regex javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, gruntjs

Any idea on how to replace a whole line if it has a specific word using regex ? I tried

```
^.*specificword.*$
```

did not work.. I have a sceanrio that i need a pattern to replace the entire line using grunt-string-replace task.. 
Trying "ServiceUrl: 'existing url'" line to be replaced with some other url

The following did not work

pattern: /ServiceUrl: (.*?) /mig,

Comment: Have you specified the "multiline" [flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)? If not, then $ will match the end of the string instead of the end of lines.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.. Just using serviceUrl.* works..